# iPhone plays particular album staticky through a particular system

Tags: iphone, itunes, audio, music

I have one album on my iPhone — A Perfect Circle, Mer De Noms — that sounds horrible when I play it through a particular system, my Harman/Kardon HK 3480 via AudioQuest Beetle (Bluetooth). It sounds great on other systems, even turned up quite loud. I don't have problems with any other albums or songs. It's the same for every song on the album.

Even when volume is lowish/medium, it sounds staticky as HELL on louder parts of the songs, and maybe sounds a bit like the signal is getting clipped, not sure.

I have already reimported the album at a higher bit rate (320kbps VBR), to no avail. I then also renamed the old imports, and imported it freshly, to avoid using the old track settings.

I retain the same compression on my iPhone as desktop. The EQ and playback level of each song is set to the default.

My iPhone has iOS 12.0.1 installed (the latest), but it had this problem with previous versions.

How can I get this album playing correctly again?

UPDATE: I actually remimported again with MP3 compression, I renamed everything before the import, and got the same result again. I'm pretty sure this has to do with the source album.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this two different ways. One was just to purchase and download the album from the iTunes store. The other was to reduce the playback volume for the album in the song/album settings in iTunes. I think the album was recored a bit loud, even though I never noticed before; and either the iPhone or the Beetle couldn't handle the volume level.